# If SCI.SOURCE="CC" , and SCI.CATEGORY should not be 'not awaiting'. I want to return the records based on this additional condition

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT sci.le_id AS le_id,
                sci.sub_profile_id AS sub_profile_id,
                sci.GROUP_ID AS GROUP_ID,
                sci.cdd_id,
                sci.crm_id,
                sci.grp_crm_id,
                sci.source,
                sci.category
  FROM table_name sci
 WHERE sci.crm_id IN (SELECT master.x_ref_id
                        FROM biz_master master, biz_pr_master pr
                       WHERE     master.x_latest_txn_id = pr.x_txn_id
                             AND pr.x_leid IS NULL
                             AND pr.GROUP_ID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then add it in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
 WHERE ......
  AND (sci.source <> 'CC' -- this condition will be true for all other sci.source
  OR sci.category <> 'not awaiting') -- This condition will be checked if sci.source = CC
```

Comment: actually , the value in sci.source is not just 'CC' , there can be many .But what i want to check is only if the value in sci.source ="CC" , then it  should check  sci.category <> 'not awaiting' . and If value in sci.source is not 'CC' , then it should return the result as is.

Comment: -   actually , the value in sci.source is not just 'CC' , there can be many .But what i want to check is only if the value in sci.source ="CC" , then it  should check  sci.category <> 'not awaiting' . and If value in sci.source is not 'CC' , then it should return the result as is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of something like `CASE`:

```
and sci.category <> case when sci.source = 'CC' then 'not awaiting'
                         else '???
                    end
```

Comment: -actually , the value in sci.source is not just 'CC' , there can be many .But what i want to check is only if the value in sci.source ="CC" , then it should check sci.category <> 'not awaiting' . and If value in sci.source is not 'CC' , then it should return the result as is.

Comment: Sample data would help. Please, edit the original question you asked and provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements (which will represent "source") and desired output based on that data.